# Datatables, adding another column in dataset but not display it in table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table in my database I would like to display content in a `datatable`. The table has 3 columns `id, name and datecreated`. I want the users to be able to delete the rows from this table by clicking a the `delete button` in each row So a graphic representation of this would look like

`|name |title| date|Delete Button|`

Before I would load data in my `datatable` by just pulling all the rows in my database and `iterating` through them whilst setting the content like this

```
                       <table id="example23" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                         <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <?php foreach ($messages as $message) {?>
                             <tr class="info">
                            <td><?php echo  $message['name']; ?> </td>
                            <td> <?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($message['datecreated'])); ?></td>
                             <td><a href="<?php echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?delete='.$message['id']; ?>"
                            <form   method="get">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-rounded" type="button" type="submit" name="submit">DELETE</button>
                            </form>
                            </td> 
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </table>
```

This was easy but overtime I noticed it's bad for 1000+ rows, it performs really bad, so I decided to `switch to server side processing` using `Ajax` to make a request like

```
('#example123').DataTable({   
  "bProcessing": true,
     "ajax":{
        url :"../public/messages", 
        type: "POST",  
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log('Error::'+xhr.responseText);
           $('#loader').hide();
        },

        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loader').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
        }
      },
```

With my backend setup like

```
   public function fetchMessages($draw, $start, $length, $query, $orderColumn, $orderDir){

//*getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT id, name, datecreated from messages";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$totalData = $stmt->affected_rows;
$totalFiltered = $totalData; 

//*Search
$sql = "SELECT id, name, datecreated from messages";
if(!empty($query)) {
    $query = "%{$query}%";  
    $sql.=" WHERE name LIKE ? )";

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $query, $query, $query);
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$totalFiltered = $stmt->affected_rows;


$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $orderColumn."   ".$orderDir."  LIMIT ".$start." ,".$length."  ORDER BY e.datecreated DESC";   
$stmt->execute();
$events = array();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $datecreated);



    while($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $message = array();
        //$message[] = $id; Once I include id, it goes into the name column and the name goes into the datecreated column
        $message[] = $name; 
        $message[] = $datecreated; 
        $messages[] =  $message;

    }

 $json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData), 
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data"            => $messages 
        );   

return $json_data;
}
```

This loads data just fine. My problem is unlike in my first solution where I used the id to delete the content I do not have the id in this table, the moment I include the `ID` in the `json` it wants  replaces `name` and `name` replaces `datecreated`. I was looking for a way where I can include `ID` in the `data` yet hide and use similar logic as used [In this the official datatable tutorial](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) to get the id and use it to delete the needed row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turns out I was looking at the issue from a very different angle. So this is what I did.

First I specified my column names, the `columns names` should have the same name as their `JSON` counterparts coming from the database.

```
         "columns": [
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "location" },
        { "data": "tickettypes" },
        { "data": "eventtype" },
        { "data": "starts",
          "type" : "date",
            "render": function (data) {
                var date = moment(data).utc().format('DD MMM, YY [at] hh:mm A');
            return date;
        } },
        { "data": "ends",
          "type" : "date",
            "render": function (data) {
                var date = moment(data).utc().format('DD MMM, YY [at] hh:mm A');
            return date;
        } },
        { "data": "datecreated",
         "type" : "date",
            "render": function (data) {
                var date = moment(data).utc().format('DD MMM, YY [at] hh:mm A');
            return date;
        }
    },
        { "data": null }

    ],
```

So if you notice their is no ID, that is because there shouldn't be. It turns out a datatable has a special object called `DT_RowId` this is where one can use to specify their own `row ID` so I did, I inserted my `ids` like

```
 $event = array();
        $event["DT_RowId"] = $id;
        $event["title"] = strlen($title) > 70 ? substr($title, 0, 70)."..." : $title; 
        $event["location"] = strlen($address) > 70 ? substr($address, 0, 70)."..." : $address; 
        $event["tickettypes"] = strlen($tickettypes) > 70 ? substr($tickettypes, 0, 70)."..." : $tickettypes;  
        $event["eventtype"] = $eventtype;
        $event["starts"] = $starts;
        $event["ends"] = $ends; 
        $event["datecreated"] = $datecreated; 
        $events[] =  $event;
```

And

```
    $response = array(
        "draw"            => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData), 
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data"            => $events);   
$stmt->close();
```

At this point I had successfully inserted the data with their equivalent IDs, all I had to do is access them with the buttons I had added in my rows So I did this

```
 $('#eventTable tbody').on( 'click', '#btndelete', function () {
   var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()
   data['DT_RowId'];//
} );
```

Took me sometime but I can't be more proud.